# Does the Stance Tuning options improve the performance of the vehicle?

Tags: need-for-speed-payback

Does changing the Camber and Height options change the vehicle performance?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, no Camber and Height [do not affect you car's handling](https://www.reddit.com/r/needforspeed/comments/7n1gdw/in_nfs_payback_does_the_stance_tuning_change/), they are purely cosmetic.

NFS Payback's customization options are not consistent on whether or not they affect your vehicle's performance. For instance, modifications like your car's spoiler or canards will affect downforce strength and improve agility at high speeds but other changes like brake discs don't have any effect.

I'd advise you to look through Payback's [wikia page](https://nfs.fandom.com/wiki/Need_for_Speed:_Payback/Visual_Customisation) to get a better idea of what modifications affect performance and what modifications don't.

Comment: As the comments on the Reddit post say, is just stupid.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Especially because camber and height did affect performance in Need For Speed 2015 (IIRC)

Answer (score 0):

I looked on the internet and it said everywhere that it does not affect performance. So, I went to the garage at the airport, put front weels all straight and the rear wheels with the widest angle. I took it for a spin with 2 turns, 1 normal brake and 1 hand brake. Back to the garage, installed the wheels opposite of what they were.

I went outside again and immediatly after the first turn i already noticed there was a big difference.

Comment: Can you also explain what that difference was?